# Change name of Application in Pipewire/Pulseaudio

Tags: c, sdl-2, pulseaudio, pipewire

I am currently trying to build a very simple Audio-Tool, which needs to change its name in `pavucontrol` and `qjackctl` on runtime. When an Application produces Audio, its name is shown in `pavucontrol`. E.g. if I use `firefox` it is shown as "Firefox". I tried the most commonly suggested solutions: Editing `argv` and using `prctl` both did not succeed.

I also searched the `pipewire` documentation but I didn't find anything useful (but maybe I am just blind).

Is it even possible? From where does `pipewire` get the name of the Application?

Here is a little test-script in C with SDL2:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

Uint8* audio_buffer = NULL;
Uint32 audio_length = 0;

void audio_callback(void* userdata, Uint8* stream, int n) {
    memset(stream, 0, n);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    SDL_Event evt;
    SDL_AudioSpec desired;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO|SDL_INIT_EVENTS);

    SDL_LoadWAV("suil.wav", &desired, &audio_buffer, &audio_length);
    desired.callback = audio_callback;

    SDL_OpenAudio(&desired, NULL);
    SDL_PauseAudio(0);


    while (1) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&evt)) {
            switch (evt.type) {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And a picture of what I would like to have changed on runtime:

[image]

(Note: The "test" would be the name in question.)

Disclaimer:
I'm not sure if this would maybe sdl-2 specific, so I added the SDL tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDL's Pipewire backend [grabs the application name in this block](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.24.0/src/audio/pipewire/SDL_pipewire.c#L1190-L1197):

```
/* Get the hints for the application name, stream name and role */
app_name = SDL_GetHint(SDL_HINT_AUDIO_DEVICE_APP_NAME);
if (!app_name || *app_name == '\0') {
    app_name = SDL_GetHint(SDL_HINT_APP_NAME);
    if (!app_name || *app_name == '\0') {
        app_name = "SDL Application";
    }
}
```

...via the [hint system](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetHint):

- [`SDL_HINT_APP_NAME`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.24.0/include/SDL_hints.h#L148-L166):

  ```
  /**
   *  \brief Specify an application name.
   * 
   * This hint lets you specify the application name sent to the OS when
   * required. For example, this will often appear in volume control applets for
   * audio streams, and in lists of applications which are inhibiting the
   * screensaver.  You should use a string that describes your program ("My Game
   * 2: The Revenge")
   *
   * Setting this to "" or leaving it unset will have SDL use a reasonable
   * default: probably the application's name or "SDL Application" if SDL
   * doesn't have any better information.
   *
   * Note that, for audio streams, this can be overridden with
   * SDL_HINT_AUDIO_DEVICE_APP_NAME.
   *
   * On targets where this is not supported, this hint does nothing.
   */
  #define SDL_HINT_APP_NAME "SDL_APP_NAME"
  ```
- [`SDL_HINT_AUDIO_DEVICE_APP_NAME`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.24.0/include/SDL_hints.h#L209-L228):

  ```
  /**
   *  \brief Specify an application name for an audio device.
   *
   * Some audio backends (such as PulseAudio) allow you to describe your audio
   * stream. Among other things, this description might show up in a system
   * control panel that lets the user adjust the volume on specific audio
   * streams instead of using one giant master volume slider.
   *
   * This hints lets you transmit that information to the OS. The contents of
   * this hint are used while opening an audio device. You should use a string
   * that describes your program ("My Game 2: The Revenge")
   *
   * Setting this to "" or leaving it unset will have SDL use a reasonable
   * default: this will be the name set with SDL_HINT_APP_NAME, if that hint is
   * set. Otherwise, it'll probably the application's name or "SDL Application"
   * if SDL doesn't have any better information.
   *
   * On targets where this is not supported, this hint does nothing.
   */
  #define SDL_HINT_AUDIO_DEVICE_APP_NAME "SDL_AUDIO_DEVICE_APP_NAME"
  ```

...and then passes the app name into Pipewire using [`PW_KEY_APP_NAME`](https://docs.pipewire.org/group__pw__keys.html#ga56fa277cca24072d0208f0ada2e8af02), [here](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.24.0/src/audio/pipewire/SDL_pipewire.c#L1257):

```
PIPEWIRE_pw_properties_set(props, PW_KEY_APP_NAME, app_name);
```

...where SDL's `PIPEWIRE_pw_properties_set()` is just a pointer to Pipewire's [`pw_properties_set()`](https://docs.pipewire.org/group__pw__properties.html#ga8ef83913ccf2abb4432ba0ebd3230516).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice, there is a Hint for this. That Idea sadly didn't cross my mind. Could solve it with just setting the hint. Thanks.

Comment: To be fair the [main `SDL_Hint` wiki page](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryHints) doesn't list either hint.

Comment: ...[which](https://github.com/libsdl-org/sdlwiki/issues/148) is a [known](https://github.com/libsdl-org/sdlwiki/issues/184) issue.